# Scaleway serverless function: DEBUG - No module named 'numpy' source=user stream=stdout

Tags: python, numpy, gitlab-ci, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to upload a serverless function using the **[serverless](https://www.serverless.com/)** toolbox on **[Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/en/)**.

It works, but I cannot include dependencies from the **requirements.txt** file.

As soon as I add import numpy, I get the error:

```bash
No module named 'numpy' source=user stream=stdout
```

In the logs.

All my configuration and environment variables are correct they are uploaded

Here is my configuration:

**Path**

```bash
.
├── README.md
└── http_function
    ├── handler.py
    ├── package.json
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── serverless.yaml
```

**requirements.txt**

```bash
numpy
```

**serverless.yaml**

```yaml
service: scaleway-python3
configValidationMode: off
provider:
  name: scaleway
  runtime: python310 # Available python runtimes are listed in documentation

  env: 
    test: test

plugins:
  - serverless-scaleway-functions
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux


package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!.gitignore'
    - '!.git/**'
    - requirements.txt

functions:
  http-function:
    handler: handler.handle
    description: "simple function that responds to a http endpoint"
    # Set minimum number of instances to 0
    minScale: 0
    # Set maximum number of instances to 10
    maxScale: 10
    # Set memory limit to 128MB
    memoryLimit: 128

    # Open to internet
    public: true
    env:
      local: local
```

**package.json**

```json
{
    "name": "python-scaleway-starter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "serverless-scaleway-functions": "^0.4.3"
    },
    "description": ""
}
```

**handler.py**

```py
import numpy as np
import json


def handle(event, context):
    """handle a request to the function
    Args:
        event (dict): request params
        context (dict): function call metadata
    """
    random_int = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(
            {
                "message": f"Hello From Python3 runtime on Serverless Framework and Scaleway Functions the random number is {random_int}"
            }
        ),
    }
```

It is deployed via a Gitlab CI:
**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
image: node:latest
# Use the Node image

stages: # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - deploy

deploy: # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy
  environment: dev
  variables:
    SCW_SECRET_KEY: $SCW_SECRET_KEY
    SCW_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID: $SCW_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID
    SCW_REGION: $SCW_REGION
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to dev..."
    - npm install -g serverless
    - npm install -g serverless-scaleway-functions
    - npm install -g serverless-python-requirements
    - cd http_function
    - serverless deploy
```

Answer (score -1):

According to https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/serverless/functions/how-to/package-function-dependencies-in-zip/, you cannot use numpy outside of a docker container, as it's using C script dependencies.
If you want to upload any other packages without C dependencies, remember to download them into a folder before pushing to scaleway!